# How to make a Z-index =1 div to occupy entire height

Tags: html, css

As shown in the image, I have a sidebar that opens over other elements (blue color) using z-index = 1. On opening the sidebar i don't want users to see any other elements other than the sidebar. But at the end of the sidebar, I'm seeing other elements part of the page as shown in the image (Sheets A, Sheets B).

I tried giving 100vh, 500vh, 100%, auto but none of these is working. Any way to make the Z-index =1 element occupy the entire vertical screen

[image]

```css
.navigationbar--open .navigationbar__body {
    max-height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

html

```html
<div className="navigationbar--open">
    <div className="navigationbar__heading">

        <div className="foldersection">
            <img src={image} className="navbar__icon" />

        </div>
        <FaSortDown />
    </div>
    <div className="navigationbar__body">

          <li>Folder A</li>
          <li>Folder B</li>
          <li>Folder C</li>

        ))}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this result by using a combination of CSS properties such as `overflow`, `display`, `height` and `width`. In my example, I make the `navbar` element occupy the entire screen by setting its `height` to `100vh` (100% of the vertical viewport) and prevent any vertical scrolling and display of other items by using the `overflow-y` property to `hidden`. When we click the `button` element, it toggles the `display` property to `flex` for the `nav` element. Example below.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
nav {
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
background:pink;
overflow-y:hidden;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;
flex-direction:column;
}

nav.open {
display:flex;
}

.btn {
position:absolute;
top:25px;right:25px;
z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content above</div>
<button class='btn'>btn</button>
<nav>
  <span>some nav item 1</span>
  <span>some nav item 1</span>
  <span>some nav item 1</span>
</nav>
<div>some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below</div>
<div>some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below</div>
<div>some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below</div>
<div>some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below some other page content above some other page content above some other page content above some other page content abovesome other page content below</div>
</body>
```